# Show that $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are share the same plane if and only if one of them is a linear combination of the other two

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I am asked to solve the following:

> Show that $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are coplanar if and only if one of them is a linear combination of the other two

The thing is: we are not supposed to use dot product.

**My solution:**

If

$$a\vec{u}+b\vec{v}+c\vec{w}=0$$

then the dot product by $\vec{u}$ gives

$$a \vec{u}\cdot \vec{u} + 0 + 0 = 0\\
a=0
$$
Dot product by $v$ gives
$$0+b \vec{v} \cdot \vec{v} + 0=0\\
b=0$$

Dot product by $w$ gives

$$0+0+c \vec{w}\cdot \vec{w}=0\\
c=0$$

So one of them must be a linear combination of the other two (since only the trivial solution is possible).

How could I do this without using dot product?

Comment: Do you have a working definition of "coplanar"?

Comment: They share the same plane (so the are linearly dependent)

Comment: "Share the same plane" isn't an easy definition to work with, but *linearly dependent* is.  Start with that and rearrange the defining equation.

Comment: Also, you can only claim the dot product $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = 0$ if $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are orthogonal.

Comment: To follow up on what eepperly16 wrote, the conclusion that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all 0 is in fact a conclusion that they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you understand each step of the following argument.

**Only if:**

The vectors $\vec u, \vec v, \vec w$ are coplanar iff $\dim(\operatorname{span}(\vec u, \vec v, \vec w)) \le 2$.  Because there are more than two vectors in the set $\{\vec u, \vec v, \vec w\}$, they must be linearly *dependent*.  Thus we can write the vector $\vec 0$ as a nontrivial linear combination of $\vec u, \vec v, \vec w$; i.e.

$$a\vec u + b\vec v + c\vec w = \vec 0$$ has at least one other solution besides $a=b=c=0$.

WLOG, assume that $a\ne 0$.  Then we can rearrange the above equation as $$\vec u = -\frac ba\vec v -\frac ca \vec w$$ which means that one of the vectors is a linear combination of the other two.

**If:**

WLOG, let $\vec u = \alpha \vec v + \beta \vec w$.  Then $1\vec u-\alpha\vec v -\beta \vec w = \vec 0$.  Therefore $\{\vec u, \vec v, \vec w\}$ is a linearly *dependent* set.  Which means that $\dim(\operatorname{span}(\vec u, \vec v, \vec w)) \lt 3$, or equivalently $\dim(\operatorname{span}(\vec u, \vec v, \vec w)) \le 2$.  This, by definition, means that  $\vec u, \vec v, \vec w$ are coplanar.$\ \ \ \square$